# Regex: section contains

Tags: java, regex

I need to know if a section of a string contains a specific word.

Example:
Search for `color="` in `<font` to `>`

```
<font color="black">                                 = <font color="black">
BlaBla <font color="red">                            = <font color="red">
<font size="2" color="white">                        = <font size="2" color="white">
<font size="2">                                      = false
<font size="10"><font color="black"><font size="10"> = <font color="black">
```

I use Java with `String.matches()`

Comment: You want to get the value of the color?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi No, I need to know if there is a HTML-tag with a color in <font>

Comment: In this use case, JSoup seems more robust than a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based just on your example test cases provided, you might be able to get away with a simple regular expression like this:

```
<font[^>]*color="[^"]+"[^>]*>
```

Demo: http://jpad.io/example/1u/36573959-example

However, as pointed out in the comments, regular expressions are generally not well-suited for processing HTML.

Answer (score 3):

For parsing HTML it should be better do it with [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/). For quick introduction start with [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this with regex but this is hazardous.

On the other hand, JSOUP is intended for that use case and very easy to use.

**Example :**

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
  Document document = Jsoup.parse("<font id=\"myFont\" color=\"black\">");
  Elements font = document.select("font");
  for (Element element : font) {
    System.out.println(element.attr("color"));
  }

}
```

**Output :**

```
black
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex:

```
(?<=\<)(\w+)[^<]*color.*?\>
```

Demo:

```
String data = "<font color=\"black\">";
String strFind = "color";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)(\\w+)[^<]*"+strFind+".*?>", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String content = matcher.group(1) == null ? matcher.group() : matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Provided sample text, it will print name of tag containing desired string. In this case it will be `font`